# java integration with neo4j database

Tags: java, neo4j

I want to connect java with neo4j database. Usually when connecting with SQL the connection string would be like

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                   "jdbc:" + this.dbms + "://" +
                   this.serverName +
                   ":" + this.portNumber + "/",
                   connectionProps);
```

Similarly for Neo4j how do we give the connection URL and let me know if we connect with the JDBC driver itself.
Please let me know.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Neo4j JDBC driver to connect to your graph as well: http://www.neo4j.org/develop/tools/jdbc

I have some notes on using it here: http://thought-bytes.blogspot.in/2014/02/migrating-flavorwocky-database-using.html